# I have 2 divs inside Container/section div but one of the two divs is being pushed out of the container div, why?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a website with Wordpress and have a question regarding my homepage. It is divided into 4 container divs, each of them taking up the entire screen. In my 4th div, I want to have something like a tab-function. Meaning, there are 4 buttons at the bottom of the container4 div and depending on which of the four buttons you click, a different content will load (content 1, 2, 3 or 4).

I found a useful code on codepen and altered it a bit for my needs but I am encountering an issues I can't seem to solve.

The buttons are wrapped in a 'button-wrap' div and then I also have the content div that encloses the 4 divs with the content that's supposed to be swapped out when clicking on the buttons. This works great with the jQuery code I have and the content divs are also all nicely lining up with the main Container 4 div. However, even though I did place the button wrap div in the container div as well, it is being pushed down into the footer of my homepage. I tried adding inline block but this doesn't do anything. The button wrap div and content div just seem to block each other. and I don't know why!

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.button').first().addClass('active');
  jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
    jQuerysiblings = jQuerythis.parent().children(),
      position = jQuerysiblings.index(jQuerythis);
    console.log(position);
    jQuery('.content div').removeClass('active').eq(position).addClass('active');
    jQuerysiblings.removeClass('active');
    jQuerythis.addClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
/* Container4 Styling */

.container4 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CDE5E1;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Tab HP Styling */

.one {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.three {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}

.four {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Tab HP BUTTON Styling */

.content {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-wrap {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.active {
  color: black;
}

div[class*="content-"] {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container4">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-1 active one">
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content-2 two"> content 2 </div>
    <div class="content-2 three"> content 3 </div>
    <div class="content-2 four"> content 4 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <a href="#" class="button">  Button 1  </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">    Button 2  </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">  Button 3  </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">  Button 4 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I will take out the 2nd issue and post it in a separate question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have given 100vh to the main container i.e. `container4`. If you will remove that it will work fine. And if you want tabs to display within 100vh of `content` element, you can try it with an absolute position.

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('.button').first().addClass('active');
  jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    var jQuerythis = jQuery(this);
    jQuerysiblings = jQuerythis.parent().children(),
      position = jQuerysiblings.index(jQuerythis);
    console.log(position);
    jQuery('.content div').removeClass('active').eq(position).addClass('active');
    jQuerysiblings.removeClass('active');
    jQuerythis.addClass('active');
  })
});
```

```css
.container4 {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CDE5E1;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/* Tab HP Styling */

.one {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.three {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: purple;
}

.four {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}


/* Tab HP BUTTON Styling */

.content {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.button-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.button {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

a.active {
  color: black;
}

div[class*="content-"] {
  display: none;
}

div.active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container4">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-1 active one">
      <h1>Content</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content-2 two"> content 2 </div>
    <div class="content-2 three"> content 3 </div>
    <div class="content-2 four"> content 4 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="button-wrap">
    <a href="#" class="button">  Button 1  </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">    Button 2  </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">  Button 3  </a>
    <a href="#" class="button">  Button 4 </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @sakpal when I remove the 100vh from the container div then it is true that the button row will no longer be overlapping with the footer. However, I can't seem to manage to get the buttons and tab content to 100% height of the screen. Meaning, the tab content will continue to have 100vh and the buttons are still pushed under the content. But I want both together fill up the 100vh

Comment: You can achieve this with flex.

Comment: @sakpal, yes you can also achieve this with flex. Please create an example to help Jana.

Comment: I have added the snippet. Hope this is what you needed.